# CMS pages not loading anymore

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

Since an update of a plugin my CMS pages dont load anymore. See screenshot:

[image: photo]

I dont know what is going wrong or why it doesn't load anymore. The plugin is off and it doesn't effect it anymore, but still it doesn't load. Please need help where to start looking or what is going wrong where.

This is what I get out of the error log:

```
2016-04-29T10:20:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Mageworx/Seobase/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /data/web/public/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2016-04-29T10:20:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Mageworx/Seobase/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /data/web/public/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2016-04-29T10:20:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Mageworx/Seobase/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/data/web/public/app/code/local:/data/web/public/app/code/community:/data/web/public/app/code/core:/data/web/public/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /data/web/public/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Comment: check your Browser Consolve

Comment: how have you disabled the plugin?

Comment: @Kothari The console doesn't show me anything?

Comment: @Kozure It has been disabled in the settings of the plugin.

Comment: @AxelDekker, check your plugin file permission

Comment: Have you disabled it in system->configuration->advanced ... this could be not enough ... please also go to the ./app/etc/modules/<your module>.xml and set <active>false</active>. This should fully disable the extension.